# Error Invalid prefix or suffix characters in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

When I try to edit table data in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 (right click in table object, Edit Top 200 rows) I receive this error: "Invalid prefix or suffix characters. (MS Visual Database Tools)".

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This happens when you try to edit the top 200 rows of a SQL Server 2012 database using the 2008 R2 SQL Server Management Studio.
Upgrade SQL Server Management Studio to 2012 or edit the rows using a SQL query.

Comment: And if 2012 does not work for you (it didn't for me - using VS 2013 Update 4) - you should try SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: We had this problem and Renzo's solution worked for us. Since we have side by side installs of SQL Server 2008 and 2012 on our server, users were accidentally using 2008 SSMS against the 2012 instance. They need to be running the one here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"